# Given a certain fixed platform, can sizeof return different size for the same type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, build, legacy-code

I have a very big legacy Visual Studio solution and in some source code a type I am interested in is `unsigned long`. I cannot change this code and I would like to know when a variable of that type, used as a counter, will rollover.

I wrote a different very small Visual Studio project with a simple program `std::cout << sizeof(unsigned long)` and I get `4`: can I assume that `sizeof(unsigned long)` gives `4` also in the big solution? Or is there some build/compiler options that can alter it?

Is there any compiler options specific to Microsoft that can alter the size of the built-in types on a per-project basis?

Comment: If you need a fixed sized integer, look in `<cstdint>`. Don't make assumptions about `unsigned long`

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, thank you, I am aware of `<cstdint>`.

Comment: I suspect you have an ulterior motive for asking this. Worth mentioning it in your post. The answer you get in that case would probably be better than a simple yes/no.

Comment: @StoryTeller I can obviously add a little bit of context :-) even if a yes/no answer based on C++ standard and/or Microsoft doc would suffice to me.

Comment: @StoryTeller I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes from Microsoft's [Data Type Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges):

> Visual C++ 32-bit and 64-bit compilers recognize the types in the table later in this article.
>
> ```
> Type          | Bytes
> unsigned long |   4
> ```

and [Fundamental Types C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx):

> **Microsoft Specific**
>
> The following table lists the amount of storage required for
>   fundamental types in Microsoft C++.
>
> ```
>                        Type                            |  Size
> float, __int32, int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long |  4 bytes
> ```

So the answer is **yes** (for Microsoft C++).

**Update:**

> Is there any compiler options specific to Microsoft that can alter the size of the built-in types on a per-project basis?

From the docs it looks like Microsoft C++ compiler guarantees it to be 4 bytes. Therefore I assume there are no options that can change this (at least for currently existing compilers).

Comment: What you wrote is correct but it does not seem to answer my question. Is there any compiler options specific to Microsoft that can alter the size of the built-in types?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson It logically follows from the docs that the size is always 4 for Microsoft C++ compilers. Therefore, I assume, it can't be changed via compiler options (at least for currently existing compilers). Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

> can I assume that sizeof(unsigned long) gives 4 also in the big solution?

Yes specifically (Windows, Visual Studio).
No in the general case.

```
sizeof( void *) : depends on the target platform.
sizeof( long  ) : standard guarantees at least 4 bytes, but it could be larger.
```

See : [SO : sizeof basic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Comment: Any reference to Microsoft doc?